# Group By with 2 Tables SQL

Tags: sql

Sorry guys, I have modified my questions because I have found part of the solutions with this code:

```
 select C.NTERCERO as Cliente, V.inumsop as Factura, V.FSOPORT,  Sum(V.MPRECIOVTA) + Sum(Miva) as Monto
    From Abanits  as C 
    Inner Join Karmovun as V
    On C.init = V.Init
    Where V.FSOPORT between current_date -240 and current_date
    Group by c.NTERCERO, V.FSOPORT, V.INUMSOP
    order by v.fsoport desc
```

and it generates this solutions:

```
Banco de America Central S,A    FVE-025599  15.03.2019  719.1600
Banco de America Central S,A    FVE-025600  15.03.2019  1737.0100
Candido Cesar Saenz FVE-025585  15.03.2019  1923.0300
Casa del Café S.A   FVE-025610  15.03.2019  161.0000
Casa del Café S.A   FVE-025602  15.03.2019  1499.6100
Casa del Café S.A   FVE-025612  15.03.2019  3559.3800
Casa del Café S.A   FVE-025604  15.03.2019  1661.3200
Casa del Café S.A   FVE-025609  15.03.2019  1210.6100

Edwin Rommel Holmann Pastora    FVE-025606  15.03.2019  2498.9400
Edwin Rommel Holmann Pastora    FVE-025607  15.03.2019  1277.7100
Edwin Rommel Holmann Pastora    FVE-025608  15.03.2019  2325.3000
```

Know I need extract only the last boucher for each client by Fecha and its amount.
Abanits is the clients table and Karmovun is the detils for each purchase.

Comment: Are you trying to use aliases for the tables or do the table names have spaces?  If you are trying to use aliases you need to use AS, Abanits AS Clientes.  If there are spaces in the table names you should bracket them, [Abanits Clientes], and use the full name in the rest of the query.

Comment: what is the Facturas table and how it's related to other two tables and where is the maximum date for the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Fecha doesn't have the time that you require to get the last Factura.

I suggest you extract your Factura number by doing a substring of the `V.inumsop`

```
substring(V.inumsop,5, len(V.inumsop)) as Numero_Factura
```

And you use this `numero de factura`, to select only the `MAX` of the grouping.

I assume that your Factura is ordered by number and the highest one should be the latest.